# Compute time complexity of a recurrence relation by repeated subsitution

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

By repeated substitution solve the following recurrence relation-

f(n) = 4f(n/2) + g(n) with g(n)∈ θ(n) and f(1)∈ θ(1)

Answer (score 0):

Just do it! `f(n) = 4 (4f(n/4) + g(n/2)) + g(n) = 4^2 f(n/2^2) + 4 g(n/2) + g(n) = 4^2(4f(n/2^3) + g(n/2^2)) + 4 g(n/2) + g(n) = 4^3 f(n/2^3) + 4^2 g(n/2^2) + 4 g(n/2) + g(n)`. Now we can generalize it by induction: `f(n) = sum_{i = 0}^{log(n)} 4^i g(n/2^i)`. As `g(n) = Theta(n)`, let replace `g(n)` with `n`. We will have, `f(n) = sum_{i = 0}^{log(n)} 4^i * n/2^i = sum_{i = 0}^{log(n)} 2^i * n = n * sum_{i = 0}^{log(n)} 2^i = n * (1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^log(n)) = n * (2^(log(n)+1)-1) = n * (2n - 1) = Theta(n^2)`.

Also, you can use the master theorem to solve it.